# Usando ng-style para uma variável booleana dentro de um ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

Tenho uma listagem desta forma :

```
<tr md-row md-select="cali" md-select-id="name" md-auto-select ng-repeat="cali in vm.calibracoes">
           <td md-cell>{{cali.idCalibracao}}</td>
           <td md-cell>{{cali.pessoa.nome}}</td>
           <td md-cell >{{cali.ativa? 'Sim' : 'Não'}}</td>
           <td md-cell>{{cali.dataCalibracao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
           <td md-cell>{{cali.dataProximaCalibracao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
           <td md-cell>

        </td>
 </tr>
```

Como eu faço para deixar o 'Sim' em azul e o 'Não' em vermelho ? 
Usando `ng-style` ou `ng-class` ? Nunca usei esses recursos do angularJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
 <td md-cell ng-style="{ 'color' : (cali.ativa) ? 'blue' : 'red' }">{{cali.ativa? 'Sim' : 'Não'}}</td>
```